# If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $b \geq 2|a|$ , then $b \geq \sqrt{b^2 - 4a^2}$

Tags: inequality

The author asks me to proof: if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers with $b \geq 2|a|$ , then $b \geq \sqrt{b^2 - 4a^2}$ by using the proposition: if $a$ and $b$ are positive real numbers, then $a + b \geq 2 \sqrt{ab}$.

I know that from $b \geq 2|a|$ follows that $b \geq 0$, but $a$ can be any real number right? So how can I use the proposition?

Comment: There is a much easier proof of the desired inequality : Since $b^2-4a^2\ge 0$ by assumption , we have $\sqrt{b^2-4a^2}\le \sqrt{b^2}=b$ , since $b$ cannot be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know that $b \geq 0$, as you mentionned. You used the fact that taking the absolute value of a real number will always give you a positive real number. You can easily check that $b-2|a|$ and $b+2|a|$ are so two positive real numbers. You can use the proposition you mentionned to get :

$2b = (b - 2|a|) + (b + 2|a|) \geq 2 \sqrt{(b-2|a|)(b+2|a|)}
\geq 2\sqrt{b^2-4|a|^2}$

You can easily conclude.